# How to compute amortization payoff date of loan

Tags: objective-c, amortized-analysis, amortization

I want to count loan amortization, but I have no idea how to compute the payoff date.

I have `Loan amount`,`Interest rate`,`Monthly paymnet`,`Loan Start date`. From these four values I want to know my Loan Payoff date in iOS.

I count `Interest`,`Monthly Amount` like as

```
double loanAmount = [self.amount doubleValue];
double intRate = [self.rate doubleValue];
double years = [self.durationCount doubleValue];
double r = intRate / 1200;
double n;
if ([self.duration isEqualToString:@"Yearly"])
{
    n = years * 12;
}
else
{
    n = years;
}
double rPower = pow(1 + r, n);
_monthlyPayment = loanAmount * r * rPower / (rPower - 1);
double annualPayment = _monthlyPayment * 12;
if ([self.duration isEqualToString:@"Yearly"])
{
    _totalAmount = annualPayment * years;
}
else
{
    _totalAmount = annualPayment;
}
self.InterestPaid=_totalAmount-loanAmount;
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: Does this work overall? Do you get the proper duration at the end? Is your question really only how to add `_durationCount` months to some start date (`NSDate`)?

Comment: #rmaddy now show my question it is not already duration of my loan it is starting date already.

Comment: This is essentially the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32911588/451475) asked six days ago. There are daily simple formulas to calculate these things, a Google should find them.

Comment: #zaph that time i want to know all things like as `Interest rate`,`Monthly payment`,`Yearly payment` but now i want to get only `Payoff date` of Loan from it's `starting date`,`Interest` and `Monthly Payment`.

Comment: Same answer:Google (or Bing) for the formula, they  are all related.

Comment: Hi you must've had success with that till now. Can I know how you found out? I've the same fields. Google couldn't help!